# List of CardViews containing lists. LinearLayout or RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create the layout below.

The layout consists of 3-4 cardviews. Inside two of the cardviews will be short lists anywhere between 0-6 items long.

I am wondering since all the cards are different and there so few of them if there would be any benefit to using a RecyclerView over a LinearLayout.

It seem to me that since the cards are all heterogeneous there wouldn't be any views the RecyclerView could 'recycle'. Or am I missing something?

[image: Layout wireframe]

Comment: `RecyclerView` can be better. as even you have 3 or 4 card but some are looking like size of half of screen . SO its good to use recyclable views. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seem to me that since the cards are all heterogeneous there
>   wouldn't be any views the RecyclerView could 'recycle'.

You are absolutely right - you can't get profit from re-using views (`ViewHolders`) by filling them with other `RecyclerView`'s item data.

The layout you show/describe is not a typical example of a *collection* and it looks quite simple (light), so in your case there is no point to implement `RecyclerView` and its `Adapter`.

> I am wondering since all the cards are different and there so few of
>   them if there would be any benefit to using a RecyclerView over a
>   LinearLayout.

Ask yourself if you would think about `RecyclerView` if your items were `FrameLayouts`? All in all, [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) is just a `FrameLayout` with some decoration :)

I would personally use `ScrollView` + `LinearLayout`. This approach is faster to implement and much easier to maintain.

I also agree with what **@Ben P.** wrote - if the simplest solution suits your needs there is no point to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one big thing **Memory consumption**, in **RecyclerView** screen will require **less memory** as only visible views are in memory. While in **LinearLayout** you will need all views in memory all the time,mean **more heap memory**.
More memory your app use, more it will be prone to **GC cycles** which will cause **jankyness or sluggish** app behaviour.

Comment: I thought the RecyclerView held onto views that had been used in the viewholder. So wouldn't there be 3-4 cardviews in memory either way?

Comment: RecyclerView makes use of a recycled view "pool", so the benefits kick in when you have enough items in your list to fill the visible portion of your recycler, plus a little more (it preloads items just off-screen so they can scroll in smoothly). Regardless of what you decide to do, I wouldn't base your decision on "performance benefits" until you've measured performance and decided that an otherwise-workable solution is too slow. Most discussion of RecyclerView's performance gains deal with lists of hundreds or thousands of items.

Comment: Lets use term "ScrollView vs RecyclerView" instead of "LinearLayout vs RecyclerView" here as you will put LinearLayout inside ScrollView.

By seeing design mock you can guess it is at least 2x the screen height. I would go with RecyclerView in this case rather than ScrollView to save memory. It is something which is already benchmark and proven so I am not sure anyone wants to do the same exercise again.

Any reason you will prefer otherwise ?